Can I use a voltage tester on knob-and-tube wiring?
I have a receptacle that ended up having knob-and-tube wiring. I want to go through each breaker and find out which circuit it's on. Could I safely use a voltage tester to bridge the two wires? Are there any considerations that would not apply with more modern romex wiring?
My tester is the Fluke T5-600 Voltage and Current Tester. I also have a Klein non contact voltage tester.



Testers test voltage potential between two separate wires.  Knob and tube, wires in cable, loose wires in conduit all work the same way.

There shouldn't be any problem with either type of tester. I would use a multimeter to check the voltage - should be ~ 120V (or a little lower - but same as everywhere else in your house except 240V circuits). If it is significantly lower then you have a problem somewhere that, given the age of the wiring, may need professional help. If it is ~ 208V or ~ 240V (or double your everywhere else voltage) then this should be on a double-breaker but might be two single breakers.
In any case, after checking the basics with a multimeter I would verify with a non-contact tester (so that you know it works properly) then play divide and conquer with the main panel and the non-contact tester.

Turn off half the breakers
Use the NCVT to see if there is power
If there is power, turn on the first half and turn off the second half and repeat
If there is no power, turn on half of the breakers that are off and repeat

Once you have narrowed things down to a single breaker you are all set. But you could find situations where multiple breakers all have to be off for a circuit to be off due to miswiring somewhere. If that's the case, you'll likely need help, particularly with old k & t.
